# Norm of an integral operator in $L^2$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let T an operator in $L^2((-1,1))$ such that $Tf(x) = \int_{-1}^{1} (xy + y^2)f(y)dy$.

Calculate the norm of $T$.

I tried calculating $\left\lVert Tf(x) \right\rVert$ first, but I got stucked with the square of the inside integral. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As known, $\|T\|^2=\|TT^\ast\|$, where $T^\ast f=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1(xy+x^2)f(y)dy$.

Since the operator $TT^\ast f=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1\left(\dfrac{2}{5}+\dfrac{2}{3}xy\right)f(y)dy$ is self-adjoint and compact, its norm is equal to the maximum modulo eigenvalue. Consider the equation $\dfrac{2}{5}\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1f(y)dy+\dfrac{2}{3}x\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1yf(y)dy=\lambda f(x)$. We can assume that $\lambda\ne0$, therefore $f(x)=c_1+c_2x$, where $c_1^2+c_2^2\ne 0$. Substituting $f(x)$ into the equation, we obtain the system $\lambda c_1-\dfrac{4}{5}c_1=0$, $\lambda c_2-\dfrac{4}{9}c_2=0$, where do we find two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\dfrac{4}{5}$, $\lambda_1=\dfrac{4}{9}$. Finally, $\|A\|=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}$.

Comment: Why is $|T\|^2=\|TT^\ast\|$? Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm a beginner with operators

Comment: But you know that $\|TT^\ast\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq1}|(TT^\ast x,x)|$ and $\|T^\ast\|=\|T\|$?

Comment: Ok, right. And why is its norm equal to the maximum modulo eigenvalue?

Comment: This is a property of a compact self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space. This is a theoretical fact from a textbook.

Comment: Oh, we haven't studied compact operators yet. Just out of curiosity: could you think of another way of solving this, without using compactness? I'm just trying to figure out how they wanted me to solve this

Comment: My solution is the standard way to solve such problems in $L_2$. See also Jacky Chong's solution, it does not require compactness. Using inequalities like Hölder, you will not get an accurate estimate, but only an overestimation (also called the norm of  Hilbert-Schmidt).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Observe
\begin{align}
Tf(x) = x\int^1_{-1} dy\ yf(y)+\int^1_{-1}dy\ y^2f(y)=: \mu x +v
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\|Tf\|_{2}^2 = \int^1_{-1} dx\ |\mu x+v|^2 =   \int^1_{-1}dx\ \mu^2x^2+\mu v x + v^2= \frac{2\mu^2}{3}+2v^2.
\end{align}
Next, observe that for any $f \in L^2(-1, 1)$, we can write
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} c_n P_n(x)  = \frac{c_0}{\sqrt{2}}+ c_1\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x+c_2\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}(3x^2-1)+\cdots
\end{align}
where $P_n$ is the normalized $n$th degree Legendre polynomial. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\|f\|_2^2= \sum^\infty_{n=0}|c_n|^2
\end{align}
with 
\begin{align}
\mu =\int^1_{-1} dy\ yf(y) =\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}c_1 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
v=\int^1_{-1} dy\ y^2f(y) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}c_0+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}c_2.
\end{align}

Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\|Tf\|_2^2=&\ \frac{2}{3}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}c_1 \right)^2+2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}c_0+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}c_2 \right)^2\\
\le&\ \frac{4}{9}c_1^2+2\left(\frac{2}{9}+\frac{8}{45}\right)(c_0^2+c_2^2)\\
\leq&\ 2\left(\frac{2}{9}+\frac{8}{45}\right)(c_0^2+c_1^2+c_2^2)= \frac{4}{5}(c_0^2+c_1^2+c_2^2)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\|T\|_\text{op} \leq \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\approx 0.894.
\end{align}

Consider $f(x) = P_0(x)+cP_2(x)$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\|Tf\|_2^2=2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}c \right)^2=\frac{4}{5}(1+c^2) = \frac{4}{5}\|f\|_2^2
\end{align}
provided $c=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$. Hence $\|T\|_\text{op} = \sqrt{4/5}$.

Comment: Can I ask you how you guessed that $f(x) = P_0(x) + cP_2(x)$ could be the right function to reach the $sup$ of the norm?

Comment: Since the computation for $ \|Tf\|_2$  only depends on $c_0, c_1$ and $c_2$ then it suffices to consider functions of the form $f(x) = c_0P_0+c_1P_1+c_2P_2$ (in short, the range of $T$ is span by $P_0, P_1, P_2$). Next, since we also know that $\|Tf\|_2 \leq \frac{4}{9}c_1^2+\frac{4}{5}(c_0^2+c_2^2)$ then it's only a matter of trial and error to attain the maximum value.