# Norm of the adjoint operator of an operator of the form $\int_{0}^{1} k(t,s)f(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I am asked to compute the adjoint of the operator $A: L^2[0,1] \longrightarrow L^2[0,1] $ defined by
$$
Af(t)=\int_{t}^{1} t (s-1/2) f(s) ds
$$
and then to compute its norm, that is $\lVert A^* \rVert$.

My attempt:

For the first part, we have that for all $f,g \in L^2[0,1]$:

\begin{align*}
\langle Af,g \rangle&= \int_{0}^{1} Af(t)g(t) dt= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_t^1  t (s-1/2) f(s) ds \right) g(t) dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{s} t (s-1/2) f(s) g(t) dt\, ds= \int_{0}^{1} f(s) \left( \int_{0}^{s} t(s-1/2)g(t)dt \right) ds
\end{align*}
and therefore
$$
A^{*}g(s)= \int_{0}^{s} t(s-1/2)g(t)dt
$$

Now, since $A$ is bounded (by $\lVert k \rVert_{2}$, where $k(t,s)=1_{[t,1]}(s)t(s-1/2) \in L^2([0,1]\times[0,1])$ for example) I know that  $\lVert A^* \rVert=\lVert A \rVert$ which led me to trying to compute $\lVert A \rVert$. One natural candidate for $\lVert A \rVert$ is precisely  $\lVert k \rVert_{2}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{ \sqrt{720} }$. I tried to find $f \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $\lVert  f \rVert_2=1$ and $\lVert  Af \rVert_2=\lVert  k \rVert_2=1$ but it wasn't such a good idea and consequently my approach is probably wrong.

Any help or suggestion?

In advance thank you.

Comment: May be use the method of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588425/norm-of-an-integral-operator-in-l2

Comment: @AnneBauval it seems like a good idea :), I'll try it! Thank you.  I haven't seen compact operators yet but the idea of $\lVert T^* T \rVert = \lVert  T \rVert ^2$ seems promising in this case.

Comment: Your $A$ is compact since it is [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator). Its Hilbert-Shmidt norm is $\|k\|_2$ but its operator nom is probably larger. I did not try.

Comment: @AnneBauval like I said I haven't studied compact operators (nor Hilbert-Schmidt norm) yet. However, with respect to your last comment, unless I misscalculated (which is totally possible) it can be proven that $\lVert A \rVert \leq \lVert  k \rVert_2$ so it can't be larger than $\lVert  k \rVert_2$.

Comment: My previous comment was only to provide you theorems you could admit, but I was (half-)wrong! Surely, [$∥A∥_{HS}=∥k∥_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator). But [$∥A∥≤\|A\|_{HS}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator#Properties)
 indeed! Sorry, now I tried to calculate but did not succeed in solving your problem.

Comment: @AnneBauval don't worry! Thanks for your help anyway :), I'm ridiculously persevering so I will keep trying, if I come up with a solution I'll write it in the answer section :) . Thanks again!